# Как растянуть элемент на всю ячейку datagrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

Такая проблема : у меня в DataGridTemplateColumn находится кнопка. Как мне сделать так, чтобы она занимала все пространство ячейки?

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
             <Button/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```